# I don't have the app but the studio says that I have it with a different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk, android-studio-3.5

I'm using Android Studio 3.5 and can't install an app from it.
My app is already on play store and I'm upgrading the app.
It keeps saying there's a same application.
Okay, so I deleted it, but it keeps saying that.

First a pop-up window saying that I will have to uninstall the existing application. I know why it happens. I develop on my laptop and my desktop at the same time so it happens all the time. And this app doesn't have my data so I've clicked okay and proceeded and there was no problem. But,

The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
Retry

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

in new. And even I don't have the app, why does it say like that???

And installation is way too quick on play store.
I think the app isn't deleted properly.

So basically, I have no app on the phone, the data, cache, apk, anything, but it keeps saying there is a same app with a different signature.

I have

1. Deleted the existing app and it still didn't work
2. Re-downloaded the app and ran and didn't work
   And as expected, it says if I wanna delete it, pushed OK. And the app is 
   automatically deleted.
3. also adb uninstall com.~~.~~ not working
4. Set debuggable true, still not working
5. Ran on a friend's phone which already has the exact same app from the store 
   and it works.
6. Tried to disable instant run but android studio 3.5 does not have that anymore.
7. Rebooted my phone.
8. Deleted caches of android studio and restarted it, as many as I could.
9. adb shell pm list packages -f : the package does not exist.
10. done adb uninstall com.~~.~~ and got Success code, but still not working

There's nothing wrong with codes.
Build works perfect. It runs perfectly on my friend's phone.

I expect for the app to run perfectly but,
the studio says

The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
Retry

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Also, installation is too slow. It wasn't slow like this.

Comment: Did you try re-booting your phone just to make sure cache is totally cleared after deleting the app?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that. Yes I did.

Comment: Seems like your particular model of phone is not playing nicely when you delete an app. Try going to the app store and hitting the uninstall option there. If it says it is not installed then install it then uninstall again using the play store uninstall option then try installing your new version once you've done this

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happen when you have multiple spaces or user in single phone, it will be helpful if you can tell about your phone model

Comment: My phone model is SM-G975N, sir. Samsung Galaxy S10+, a Korean model for KT network.

Comment: do you multiple user in that phone?

Comment: God...... I've downloaded app in a secret folder. yes.. and it worked.... thank you